# Upgrade ruby for Orange pi ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rvm

Trying to install huginn on orangePI (ubuntu), but it requires `Ruby version >= 2.2.2`, while I have 2.1.2
So I tryed to install new ruby 2.3.3, it takes a long and it goes to `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3`

now running bundle to build huginn and it says:
`bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

so I tryed to set ruby 2.3.3 as default:
`rvm --default use 2.3.3`
result are:
`bash: rvm: command not found`

I tryed add path, but still no luck:
`echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc`

I found rvm in `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm/`
tryed running it: 
`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm use ruby-2.3.3`
result are: `Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): [2.2.2,RUBY_VERSION].max.
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`

So after a for days of searching how build huginn I'm stacked on ruby. I have ruby 2.3.3 but bundle now says:
`bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Just have not idea how to fix ruby, because rvm says:
`bash: rvm: command not found`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you actually check that */usr/bin/ruby2.1* exists? Maybe you just need to adjust the shebang line in your scripts: it is usually more future-proof and portable to write `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` rather than to hard-code a particular path and version (that is, of course, assuming that an executable file named “*ruby*” indeed exists in your PATH).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Ruby 2.1 does not exist, I have to uninstall it, as it was described in manual for ruby 2.3.3. The problem is - system somewhere still have "pointer" to ruby 2.1. As far I understand, RVM can fix that, but I can not run it - bash: rvm: command not found. After ruby 2.1    was uninstalled rvm not present any more as well. I tried to install it back, but it comes with old ruby and again the circle back - huginn says that ruby version is too old. Uninstall->no rvm, no ruby->reinstall->ruby outdated. While there is ruby 3.3.3. I already thinking to give up with huginn...

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Ruby, — just expressed my suspicions that there may be some generic shell / scripting / file-search issue rather than Ruby- or RVM-specific one.